# JDO: Exception when trying to detach objects

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo, datanucleus

Im trying to use the datastore in google app engine. I'm able to make an object persistent and can retrieve it by id. But I can't query it.

This is my entity:

```
package my.company.domain;

import javax.jdo.annotations.IdGeneratorStrategy;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PersistenceCapable;
import javax.jdo.annotations.Persistent;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PrimaryKey;

@PersistenceCapable(detachable="true")
public class User {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    long key;   

    @Persistent
    private String name;

    @Persistent
    private String password;

    @Persistent
    private boolean adminPrivileges;

//getters & setters
}
```

And my Unit Test:

```
public void persistAndFindUserTest(){

        User user = new User();
        user.setName(johnDoe");
        user.setPassword("password");

        UserService userService = new DefaultUserService();
        user = userService.createUserInDatabase(user);

        User userFromPersistence = userService.getUserById(user.getKey());
        Assert.assertEquals(user.getName(), userFromPersistence.getName());

        Assert.assertNotNull(userService.findUserByName("johnDoe"));
}
```

findUserByName is defined als follows:

```
public List<User> findUserByEmail(String email){
        PersistenceManager persistenceManager = PMF.get()
                .getPersistenceManager();

        Query q = persistenceManager.newQuery(User.class);
        q.setFilter("email == emailParam");
        q.declareParameters("String emailParam");
    q.setUnique(false);

        List<User> results = null;
        try {
            results = (List<User>) q.execute(email);
        } finally {
            results = (List<User>)persistenceManager.detachCopyAll(results);
            q.closeAll();
        }
        return results;
    }
```

Following Exception occurs (line 116 is where I try to detach the result list):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.QueryEntityPKFetchFieldManager.fetchLongField(QueryEntityPKFetchFieldManager.java:74)
    at org.datanucleus.identity.IdentityUtils.getApplicationIdentityForResultSetRow(IdentityUtils.java:101)    
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.EntityUtils.entityToPojo(EntityUtils.java:1009)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.DatastoreQuery$2.apply(DatastoreQuery.java:227)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.DatastoreQuery$2.apply(DatastoreQuery.java:224)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.LazyResult.resolveNext(LazyResult.java:96)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.LazyResult$LazyAbstractListIterator.computeNext(LazyResult.java:229)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:131)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:126)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.LazyResult$AbstractListIterator.hasNext(LazyResult.java:183)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.detachCopyAll(JDOPersistenceManager.java:1213)
    at ch.mttb.clientmanagement.service.impl.DefaultUserService.findUserByEmail(DefaultUserService.java:116)
    at ch.mttb.clientmanagement.service.test.UserServiceTest.persistUserTest(UserServiceTest.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Im using the jars from the GAE SDK 1.7.2, the datanucleus jars are the following:

datanucleus-api-jdo-3.1.0-m3.jar
datanucleus-api-jpa-3.1.0-m3.jar
datanucleus-appengine-2.1.0-final.jar
datanucleus-core3.1.0-m5.jar

My enhancer.log files still are empty. I configured Logging as follows:
Put log4j.properites und WEB-INF
Put log4j-1.2.17.jar to the build path

log4j.properties:

```
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] - %m%n


log4j.category.DataNucleus.JDO=WARN, A1
log4j.category.DataNucleus.Persistence=WARN, A1
log4j.category.DataNucleus.Cache=WARN, A1
log4j.category.DataNucleus.MetaData=WARN, A1
log4j.category.DataNucleus.General=WARN, A1
log4j.category.DataNucleus.Utility=WARN, A1
log4j.category.DataNucleus.Transaction=WARN, A1
log4j.category.DataNucleus.Datastore=WARN, A1
log4j.category.DataNucleus.ClassLoading=WARN, A1
log4j.category.DataNucleus.Plugin=WARN, A1
log4j.category.DataNucleus.ValueGeneration=WARN, A1
log4j.category.DataNucleus.Enhancer=WARN, A1
log4j.category.DataNucleus.SchemaTool=WARN, A1
```

Im using eclipse juno.

Log Output when runnig junit test:

```
18:3811,450 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Plugin] - Plugin Registry "org.datanucleus.plugin.EclipsePluginRegistry" not found. Falling back to DataNucleus registry. Reason : Class "org.eclipse.core.runtime.RegistryFactory" was not found in the CLASSPATH. Please check your specification and your CLASSPATH..
18:3811,452 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Plugin] - Using PluginRegistry org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry
18:3811,464 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Plugin] - Registering bundle org.datanucleus.api.jpa version 3.1.0.m3 at URL file:/C:/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.2.1/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.2.1/lib/opt/user/datanucleus/v2/datanucleus-api-jpa-3.1.0-m3.jar.
18:3811,471 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Plugin] - Loading extension points from plug-in file jar:file:/C:/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.2.1/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.2.1/lib/opt/user/datanucleus/v2/datanucleus-api-jpa-3.1.0-m3.jar!/plugin.xml.
18:3811,472 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Plugin] - Loading extensions from plug-in file jar:file:/C:/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.2.1/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.2.1/lib/opt/user/datanucleus/v2/datanucleus-api-jpa-3.1.0-m3.jar!/plugin.xml.
18:3811,476 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Plugin] - Registering bundle org.datanucleus version 3.1.0.m5 at URL file:/C:/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.2.1/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.2.1/lib/opt/user/datanucleus/v2/datanucleus-core-3.1.0-m5.jar.
18:3811,506 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Plugin] - Loading extension points from plug-in file jar:file:/C:/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.2.1/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.2.1/lib/opt/user/datanucleus/v2/datanucleus-core-3.1.0-m5.jar!/plugin.xml.
18:3811,535 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Plugin] - Loading extensions from plug-in file jar:file:/C:/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.2.1/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.2.1/lib/opt/user/datanucleus/v2/datanucleus-core-3.1.0-m5.jar!/plugin.xml.
18:3811,540 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Plugin] - Registering bundle com.google.appengine.datanucleus version 2.1.0 at URL file:/C:/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.2.1/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.2.1/lib/opt/user/datanucleus/v2/datanucleus-appengine-2.1.0-final.jar.
18:3811,549 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Plugin] - Loading extension points from plug-in file jar:file:/C:/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.2.1/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.2.1/lib/opt/user/datanucleus/v2/datanucleus-appengine-2.1.0-final.jar!/plugin.xml.
18:3811,554 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Plugin] - Loading extensions from plug-in file jar:file:/C:/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.2.1/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.2.1/lib/opt/user/datanucleus/v2/datanucleus-appengine-2.1.0-final.jar!/plugin.xml.
18:3811,558 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Plugin] - Registering bundle org.datanucleus.api.jdo version 3.1.0.m3 at URL file:/C:/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.2.1/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.2.1/lib/opt/user/datanucleus/v2/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.1.0-m3.jar.
18:3811,564 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Plugin] - Loading extension points from plug-in file jar:file:/C:/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.2.1/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.2.1/lib/opt/user/datanucleus/v2/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.1.0-m3.jar!/plugin.xml.
18:3811,567 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Plugin] - Loading extensions from plug-in file jar:file:/C:/eclipse/plugins/com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle_1.7.2.1/appengine-java-sdk-1.7.2.1/lib/opt/user/datanucleus/v2/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.1.0-m3.jar!/plugin.xml.
18:3811,587 INFO  [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Property datanucleus.appengine.singletonPMFForName unknown - will be ignored
18:3811,587 INFO  [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Property datanucleus.appengine.autoCreateDatastoreTxns unknown - will be ignored
18:3811,602 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Java types support initialising ...
18:3811,603 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Java type [B (persistent=true, DFG=true, embedded=true)
18:3811,604 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Java type [C (persistent=true, DFG=true, embedded=true)
18:3811,604 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Java type [D (persistent=true, DFG=true, embedded=true)
18:3811,604 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Java type [F (persistent=true, DFG=true, embedded=true)
18:3811,604 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Java type [I (persistent=true, DFG=true, embedded=true)
18:3811,604 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Java type [J (persistent=true, DFG=true, embedded=true)
18:3811,604 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Java type [S (persistent=true, DFG=true, embedded=true)
18:3811,604 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Java type [Z (persistent=true, DFG=true, embedded=true)
18:3811,605 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Java type [Ljava.lang.Boolean; (persistent=true, DFG=true, embedded=true)

same for many types

18:3811,651 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Java type [Lcom.google.appengine.api.users.User; (persistent=true, DFG=true, embedded=true)

same for typed Collections, Lists and Sets


18:3811,659 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Java types support loaded
18:3811,659 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Type converter support initialising ...
18:3811,660 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Added converter for java.math.BigDecimal<->java.lang.String using org.datanucleus.store.types.converters.BigDecimalStringConverter

lot more converters added...

18:3811,667 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Added converter for java.util.UUID<->java.lang.String using org.datanucleus.store.types.converters.UUIDStringConverter
18:3811,667 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - TypeConverter for javax.time.calendar.LocalDate<->java.lang.String ignored since java type not present in CLASSPATH
18:3811,668 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - TypeConverter for javax.time.calendar.LocalTime<->java.lang.String ignored since java type not present in CLASSPATH
18:3811,669 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - TypeConverter for javax.time.calendar.LocalTime<->java.lang.Long ignored since java type not present in CLASSPATH
18:3811,669 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - TypeConverter for javax.time.calendar.LocalDateTime<->java.lang.String ignored since java type not present in CLASSPATH
18:3811,669 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Type converter support loaded
18:3811,670 DEBUG [DataNucleus.MetaData] - MetaDataManager : Input=(XML,Annotations), XML-Validation=false, XML-Suffices=(persistence=*.jdo, orm=orm, query=*.jdoquery), JDO-listener=true
18:3811,670 DEBUG [DataNucleus.MetaData] - Registering listener for metadata initialisation
18:3811,674 DEBUG [DataNucleus.MetaData] - Listener found initialisation for persistable class my.company.domain.User
18:3811,676 DEBUG [DataNucleus.MetaData] - MetaData of type "jdo" for class "my.company.domain.User" NOT found at /META-INF/package.jdo

same for many different locations

18:3811,724 DEBUG [DataNucleus.MetaData] - Class "my.company.domain.User" has been specified with JDO annotations so using those.
18:3811,743 DEBUG [DataNucleus.MetaData] - Populating Meta-Data for class my.company.domain.User.
18:3811,743 DEBUG [DataNucleus.MetaData] - MetaData of type "orm" for class "my.company.domain.User" NOT found at /META-INF/package.orm

same for many different locations

18:3811,755 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore] - Creating StoreManager for datastore
18:3811,772 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Connection] - Registered transactional connection factory under name "appengine"
18:3811,773 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Connection] - Registered nontransactional connection factory under name "appengine-nontx"
18:3811,804 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore] - ======================= Datastore =========================
18:3811,805 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore] - StoreManager : "appengine" (com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreManager)
18:3811,805 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore] - AutoStart : mechanism=None, mode=Quiet
18:3811,805 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore] - Datastore : read-write
18:3811,805 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore] - Schema Control : AutoCreate(None), Validate(None)
18:3811,805 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore] - Query Languages : [JDOQL, JPQL]
18:3811,805 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore] - Queries : Timeout=0
18:3811,805 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore] - ===========================================================
18:3811,805 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore] - StorageVersion : READ_OWNED_CHILD_KEYS_FROM_PARENTS
18:3811,805 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore] - Default Relation Mode : owned
18:3811,805 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore] - ===========================================================
18:3811,819 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore] - StoreManager now created
18:3811,819 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - ================= Persistence Configuration ===============
18:3811,819 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - DataNucleus Persistence Factory - Vendor: "DataNucleus"  Version: "3.1.0.m5"
18:3811,819 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - DataNucleus Persistence Factory initialised for datastore URL="appengine" driver="" userName=""
18:3811,819 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - JDK : 1.7.0_05 on Windows 7
18:3811,819 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Persistence API : JDO
18:3811,819 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Plugin Registry : org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry
18:3811,820 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Standard Options : pm-singlethreaded, retain-values, nontransactional-read, nontransactional-write, serverTimeZone=UTC
18:3811,820 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Persistence Options : reachability-at-commit managed-relations(checked) deletion-policy=JDO2
18:3811,820 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Transactions : type=RESOURCE_LOCAL mode=datastore isolation=read-committed
18:3811,820 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Value Generation : txn-isolation=read-committed connection=New
18:3811,820 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - ClassLoading : jdo
18:3811,820 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Cache : Level1 (soft), Level2 (soft, mode=UNSPECIFIED), QueryResults (soft), Collections/Maps 
18:3811,820 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - ===========================================================
18:3811,823 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Cache] - Level 2 Cache of type "soft" initialised
18:3811,849 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Implementation creator not configured. Due to that, support for 'persistent interfaces' ("PersistenceManager.newInstance()") was disabled!
18:3811,851 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Cache] - Level 1 Cache of type "soft" initialised
18:3811,855 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Object Manager "org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@3e5b3b80" opened for datastore "com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreManager@579f707b" with txn="org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl@2491c82e"
18:3811,859 DEBUG [DataNucleus.MetaData] - Initialising Meta-Data for class my.company.domain.User.
18:3811,860 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Making object persistent : "my.company.domain.User@78871dc5"
18:3811,882 INFO  [DataNucleus.MetaData] - Performing appengine-specific metadata validation for my.company.domain.User
18:3811,883 INFO  [DataNucleus.MetaData] - Finished performing appengine-specific metadata validation for my.company.domain.User
18:3811,904 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Managing Persistence of Class : my.company.domain.User [Table : my.company.domain.User, InheritanceStrategy : new-table]
18:3811,918 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Connection] - Created ManagedConnection using DatastoreService = com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl@79e479a3
18:3811,919 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Connection] - Connection added to the pool : com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl$DatastoreManagedConnection@7303d690 for key=org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@3e5b3b80 in factory=ConnectionFactory:nontx[com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl@fbc2ee]
18:3811,921 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore.Native] - Putting entity of kind User with key User(no-id-yet) as {tenantId[0], password[password], name[johnDoe], adminPrivileges[false], key[0], }
Okt 11, 2012 6:38:11 PM com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.LocalDatastoreService init
INFO: Local Datastore initialized: 
    Type: Master/Slave
    Storage: In-memory
18:3812,064 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Cache] - Object "my.company.domain.User@78871dc5" (id="my.company.domain.User:1") added to Level 1 cache (loadedFlags="[YYYYY]")
18:3812,064 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Connection] - Connection found in the pool : com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl$DatastoreManagedConnection@7303d690 for key=org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@3e5b3b80 in factory=ConnectionFactory:nontx[com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl@fbc2ee]
18:3812,064 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - ObjectManager.internalFlush() process started using ordered flush - 1 dirty objects
18:3812,066 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Cache] - Query Cache of type "org.datanucleus.query.cache.SoftQueryCompilationCache" initialised
18:3812,067 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Cache] - Query Cache of type "org.datanucleus.store.query.cache.SoftQueryDatastoreCompilationCache" initialised
18:3812,068 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Cache] - Query Cache of type "org.datanucleus.store.query.cache.SoftQueryResultsCache" initialised
18:3812,068 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - ObjectManager.internalFlush() process finished
18:3812,070 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Cache] - Object "my.company.domain.User@78871dc5" (id="1") added to Level 2 cache (fields="[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]", version="")
18:3812,070 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Lifecycle] - Object "my.company.domain.User@78871dc5" (id="my.company.domain.User:1") has a lifecycle change : "P_NEW"->"P_NONTRANS"
18:3812,070 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Transaction] - Object "my.company.domain.User@78871dc5" (id="my.company.domain.User:1") being evicted from transactional cache
18:3812,071 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Detaching copy of object : "my.company.domain.User@78871dc5" (depth=0) - will be "my.company.domain.User@43ae24e3"
18:3812,073 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Connection] - Connection found in the pool : com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl$DatastoreManagedConnection@7303d690 for key=org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@3e5b3b80 in factory=ConnectionFactory:nontx[com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl@fbc2ee] but owner object closing so closing connection
18:3812,073 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Connection] - Connection removed from the pool : com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl$DatastoreManagedConnection@7303d690 for key=org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@3e5b3b80 in factory=ConnectionFactory:nontx[com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl@fbc2ee]
18:3812,073 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Disconnecting my.company.domain.User@78871dc5 from StateManager[pc=my.company.domain.User@78871dc5, lifecycle=P_NONTRANS]
18:3812,073 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Cache] - Object with id="my.company.domain.User:1" being removed from Level 1 cache [current cache size = 1]
18:3812,073 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Cache] - Level 1 Cache cleared
18:3812,074 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Object Manager "org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@3e5b3b80" closed
18:3812,075 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Cache] - Level 1 Cache of type "soft" initialised
18:3812,075 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Object Manager "org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@1f6aa236" opened for datastore "com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreManager@579f707b" with txn="org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl@11bf9757"
18:3812,077 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Cache] - Object with id "my.company.domain.User:1" not found in Level 1 cache [cache size = 0]
18:3812,077 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Cache] - Object "my.company.domain.User@6ccc45d2" (id="my.company.domain.User:1") added to Level 1 cache (loadedFlags="[NNYNN]")
18:3812,079 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Cache] - Object with id="my.company.domain.User:1" taken from Level 2 cache (fields="[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]", version="") - represented as "my.company.domain.User@6ccc45d2"
18:3812,079 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Lifecycle] - Object "my.company.domain.User@6ccc45d2" (id="my.company.domain.User:1") has a lifecycle change : "P_CLEAN"->"P_NONTRANS"
18:3812,079 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Transaction] - Object "my.company.domain.User@6ccc45d2" (id="my.company.domain.User:1") being evicted from transactional cache
18:3812,079 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Transaction] - Object "my.company.domain.User@6ccc45d2" (id="my.company.domain.User:1") is not transactional
18:3812,079 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Connection] - Created ManagedConnection using DatastoreService = com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl@18d1287b
18:3812,079 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Connection] - Connection added to the pool : com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl$DatastoreManagedConnection@4bb8aff7 for key=org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@1f6aa236 in factory=ConnectionFactory:nontx[com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl@fbc2ee]
18:3812,080 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore.Native] - Getting entity of kind User with key User(1)
18:3812,088 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Detaching copy of object : "my.company.domain.User@6ccc45d2" (depth=0) - will be "my.company.domain.User@13997783"
18:3812,088 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Connection] - Connection found in the pool : com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl$DatastoreManagedConnection@4bb8aff7 for key=org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@1f6aa236 in factory=ConnectionFactory:nontx[com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl@fbc2ee] but owner object closing so closing connection
18:3812,088 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Connection] - Connection removed from the pool : com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl$DatastoreManagedConnection@4bb8aff7 for key=org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@1f6aa236 in factory=ConnectionFactory:nontx[com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl@fbc2ee]
18:3812,088 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Disconnecting my.company.domain.User@6ccc45d2 from StateManager[pc=my.company.domain.User@6ccc45d2, lifecycle=P_NONTRANS]
18:3812,088 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Cache] - Object with id="my.company.domain.User:1" being removed from Level 1 cache [current cache size = 1]
18:3812,088 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Cache] - Level 1 Cache cleared
18:3812,089 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Object Manager "org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@1f6aa236" closed
18:3812,090 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Cache] - Level 1 Cache of type "soft" initialised
18:3812,090 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Persistence] - Object Manager "org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@5244c8cc" opened for datastore "com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreManager@579f707b" with txn="org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl@21daf346"
18:3812,107 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Query] - JDOQL Query : Compiling "SELECT UNIQUE FROM my.company.domain.User WHERE name == nameParam PARAMETERS String nameParam"
18:3812,115 DEBUG [DataNucleus.General] - Class String was resolved to be java.lang.String. It wasnt defined fully-qualified so had to be looked up; you can avoid the lookup (and improve performance) by fully-qualifying the class in the query.
18:3812,122 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Query] - JDOQL Query : Compile Time = 15 ms
18:3812,123 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Query] - QueryCompilation:
  [filter:DyadicExpression{PrimaryExpression{name}  =  ParameterExpression{nameParam}}]
  [symbols: nameParam type=java.lang.String, this type=my.company.domain.User]
18:3812,123 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Query] - JDOQL Query : Executing "SELECT UNIQUE FROM my.company.domain.User WHERE name == nameParam PARAMETERS String nameParam" ...
18:3812,125 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Query] - Query compiled as : Kind=my.company.domain.User Filter : name=johnDoe
18:3812,130 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Datastore.Native] - Executing query in datastore for SELECT UNIQUE FROM my.company.domain.User WHERE name == nameParam PARAMETERS String nameParam
18:3812,146 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Connection] - Created ManagedConnection using DatastoreService = com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl@3e36cb
18:3812,146 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Connection] - Connection added to the pool : com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl$DatastoreManagedConnection@747f498c for key=org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl@5244c8cc in factory=ConnectionFactory:nontx[com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastoreConnectionFactoryImpl@fbc2ee]
18:3812,146 DEBUG [DataNucleus.Query] - JDOQL Query : Execution Time = 23 ms
```

(I removed several duplicate lines)

Kind regards,
michael

Comment: what's the point in running your app if you don't enhance the classes successfully? Suggest you debug how you're enhancing things...

Comment: how can I debug the enhancement?

Comment: define a log4j.properties for the enhancer and then look in the log?

Comment: Thanks. I set the log level to DEBUG, there was no output, but the enhancement was successful (according to console output). But it does not change anything. I still get the same error messages...

Comment: There is always output to the log, so obviously not configured. You can easily check if classes are enhanced by using a decompiler like http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui  and then when happy they are, look at the log for your application usage; everything is logged

Comment: Ok, enhancing seems to work now. But the error described above stays the same. Any suggestions?

Comment: Define what versions of jars you're using, because they aren't the latest. LOok in the log (as already said)

Comment: I edited the original post to add some more information about logging and versions.

Comment: When debugging I would have thought it advisable to set logging to DEBUG level, since you'll never see anything (other than blatant errors otherwise). This will show things such as the query used in the DB, and when you invoke a query you get a block of log entries. That is your basis for debugging what is happening. GAE has many testcases over at http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Ftests%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fappengine%2Fdatanucleus%253Fstate%253Dclosed and all pass so you must be doing something "different" so perhaps compare with those

Comment: I edited once more and added log output, a unit test, changed description etc. The issue is really about querying entities.